# Why does node express req.session disappear with redis?

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

Node.js express sessions work perfectly for me with this code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    cookie: {maxAge: pembapp.dayInMilliseconds * 180},
    secret: 'mysecret',
    key: 'mykey'
}));
```

I can access req.session.whatever with no problem.

Now I want to use redis to store session data in case a server restart is needed, so the code becomes this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    cookie: {maxAge: pembapp.dayInMilliseconds * 180},
    secret: 'mysecret',
    key: 'mykey',
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        db: 2,
        prefix: 'myprefix',
        pass: 'mypasswd'
    })
}));
```

When I add the redis code, req.session is now undefined! Can't figure this out for the life of me. Why would req.sesion "disappear" when I add a redis store for sessions???

Answer (score 1):

I think we can close this one out. Perhaps I wasn't connecting to redis when req.session was undefined. I did find that I needed to explicitly call req.session.save() when using redis, which wasn't needed without redis.

Judging from the questions I've seen out there, ff someone could create a clear node.js example using redis-connect for persistent sessions, for node newbies, starting from scratch, I think you'd make a bunch of folks very happy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is connecting to the Redis database?

Comment: Yes, it's connecting. (I changed the redis loglevel to verbose and it shows the connection.)